# Error of type: The samAccount IdentityType must be in the form of

Tags: c#

The samAccountName IdentityType must be in the form "domainname\username", "machinename\username" or "username"

This error is at line 726 of my code

I have tried to research into this and tried various solutions from Stackoverflow but still not working.

```
public void GetUsersInGroup(string groupName)
    {
        try
        {
            string domainName = 
Properties.Settings.Default.App_CompanyDomain;
            PrincipalContext ctx = new 
PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domainName);
            GroupPrincipal grp = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, 
IdentityType.SamAccountName, groupName); --> ERROR HERE
            ListView lvwListView = this.lvwAttributes;
            ListViewItem itmListItem = default(ListViewItem);
```

I would like to display the groups and users within that group in my list View

Comment: What is the value of `groupName`?

Answer (score 0):

Check your groupName value. it is empty so you got that error.